# Accessing an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access an object inside an object but i have trouble figure out how.

```
{
  id: "335f",
  symbol: "fr",
  name: "nom",
  categories: [
    "Langue"
  ],
  localization: {
    fr: "bonjour",
    en: "hello",
  },
```

I would like to access 'fr' inside of 'localization';

I managed to console log data.localization but i can't access only the fr (it log everything)

```
    const [data, setData] = useState({ coin: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(url);
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

console.log(data.localization)
```

Comment: I tried  ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'fr' of undefined```

Comment: This is likely an async problem. Your `console.log` is not within the `async` function...

Comment: This is an async problem. the property just isn't there yet when you're logging it

Comment: Use the value in a data binding rather than a console log.

Comment: well `result` should be just normal JS object that contains all you need. Nothing reactjs related (besides misuse of `console.log` outside of async context)

Answer (score 0):

Just move `console.log(data.localization)` inside async context, so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(url);
        setData(result.data);
        console.log(result.data.localization);
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, so if i want to fetch another object inside this object do i have to create another useEffect and useState ?

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean in context of original question